# Xunit test function with Socket connection( ModbusTCP/IP)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sockets, xunit, modbus-tcp

First I would like to apologize for my bad English. Its not my native language.

I have programmed a API to communicate with a specific motor controller.
The connection between the API and the motor controller is over ModbusTCP/IP. I have used a Socket connection to realize this, which sends and receives byte arrays.

Now I have some functional problems, which I want to solve with writing unit tests to identify the problems, because the controller returns different data based on the current state in it and this makes it hard to debug.

I want to use Xunit for the tests, because I used this in some other projects.
But I have no idea how to start the unit tests for functions which are using Socket connections.
It is hard to explain how the logic works in my code, but it is easy to understand if you have a look on it, if you are interested to help me.

You can have a look on my project on Github:
https://github.com/SimonOVT/DryveD1API/tree/Basic-Features

For example:
The motor controller has a status word. I can request this by:

```
data = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 0, 43, 13, 0, 0, 0, 96, 65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2}
_ = s.Send(data, data.Length, 0);
byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[24];
_ = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
```

The bytesReceived would look like this: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 43, 13, 0, 0, 0, 96, 65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 33, 2]

I can affect the StatusWord if I write something to the ControlWord from the motor controller which works the same like reading the StatusWord.

How can I fake data in bytesReceived for a function which would contain this communication logic ?:

1. Read StatusWord: Expect my fake data.
2. Write the ControlWord.
3. Read StatusWord: Expect different fake data.

I would like to start testing the Init function in this Controller which basically has this logic in it.
https://github.com/SimonOVT/DryveD1API/blob/Basic-Features/DryveD1API/Controllers/InitController.cs

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and never tried to test the actual Receive event. What i did was to unit test the function after the Receive event. In most cases that function probably will not return any data (so, you can not unit test the function directly).

In that scenario you may log all messages from that function (eg) to a text file and afterwards you can unit test the results of the function.